# Is Lottery probability really the same for all combos?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

http://justwebware.com/uklotto/uklotto.html

Test run quickpick

Test run 1,2,3,4,5,6

Test run (single digit,teens,twenties,twenties,thirties,forties)

1000 times or more each cycle for as many cycles as you want.

Seems like the $returns are not the same...why?

**Is it better to chase randomly or aim at a fixed point to hit a moving target? For which, can you strike the target more frequently in a same timeframe?**

Comment: Why would some combos have more probability than others? They are supposed to be equally distributed. Maybe, the program that simulates that is not perfectly programmed, it is difficult to recreate a _truly random_ (whatever that means...) computer program.

Comment: It is the same for real lottery statistical data too

Comment: Well, whatever the reasons are, they are not mathematical reasons in the sense that if what you say is truly happening (which seems to be true in that program, if you test and compare the odds during 30 years for 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 10,20,30,25,35,45 for example) it is because the nature of the method they use to pick the numbers randomly which is giving more chance to some numbers...

Comment: I think that a sample of size 1000 is too small...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the website is doing (a quick explanation would be nice), but I suspect your question has to do with why the simulation results aren't the same.

It's because the simulation only runs a small *sample* of tests.  If you run your simulations longer, with more samples, the results should be closer to the 'true' answer.

For example, if you flip a fair coin 10 times, you may get 4 H and 6 T.  It doesn't mean your simulation was wrong or that the probability of H and T are not 50%.  This result is totally normal due to random chance.

If you flipped a fair coin 1000 times, you might get a result of 4990 H and 5010 T, in other words 49.9% H and 50.1% T, which is much closer to the 'true' answer in percentage terms.

Comment: One more note: the fact that running more simulations will give you results closer to the 'true' answer is due to the law of large numbers.

Comment: But there is something else going on the site, because (for some reason related to the programming (I think) it is true that for some strings of numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 gives, in the same amount of simulations (say lottery for 30 years), repeteadly different results than other strings

Comment: @ZangoLotino: So report some numbers: how many games, how many winning tickets